# -cpu-set in openmpi doesn't work as it suppose to be

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

I have 4 hosts to run an openmpi application `wrf.exe`. There are 48 cores(24 per socket,2 socket per node) on each host.

I wanna run 40 processes to handle the application. Each node will run 10 processes on 10 cores (0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18).

Here are what I tried but I didn't get the mpi manner as I suppose  to be.

1. `mpirun --hostfile=4hosts --cpu-set 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 ...`. 10 cores run at 100% util of each node. But over 100 of processes `wrf.exe` run on each node.
2. `mpirun --hostfile=4hosts -np 40 --cpu-set 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 ...`. 40 processes of wrf.exe runs on the host where I start the application. Only 10 cores on the host run at 100% util.
3. 

`mpirun --hostfile=4hosts -np 40 -N 10 --cpu-set 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 ...`

`mpirun --hostfile=4hosts -N 10 --cpu-set 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 ...`

`mpirun --hostfile=4hosts ---map-by ppr:10:node  --cpu-set 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18 ...`

All got errors:

```
Conflicting directives for mapping policy are causing the policy
to be redefined:

  New policy:   RANK_FILE
  Prior policy:  UNKNOWN

Please check that only one policy is defined.
```

There are four ip in my hostfile which indicates the hosts I would like to run my application. I'm using openmpi on centos7.6.

How to use -cpu-set in mpirun to run total 40 process on 4 node, 10 process on specified cores on each node?

Comment: It seems that cpu set does not work in openmpi v4.0.x. It works in openmpi-v5.0.x or master branch. I have update my openmpi.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cpu set does not work in openmpi v4.0.x. It works in openmpi-v5.0.x or master branch. I have update my openmpi.